# Тире в однородных членах(?)

Tags: тире

...сослали: кого (—) на юг, кого (—) на север.
Нужны ли тире в скобках? У автора только второе тире.

Comment: Приведите предложение целиком.

Comment: Авторский текст:
Деды мои были крепкими хозяевами, семьи имели большие, работали от зари до зари. Поэтому и не голодали, поэтому …их и раскулачили, сослали: кого на юг, кого — на север.

Comment: А что там за многоточие?

Comment: Многоточие авторское, означает (ИМХО) паузу-удивление.

Comment: Так оно ж должно примыкать к предыдущему слову, а не к следующему.

Comment: Согласен, авторская ошибка-опечатка.

Comment: А по существу вопроса есть ответ?

Comment: Что же вы так быстро приняли ответ? Он неправильный, там нет неполных предложений. Просто хотел ответить позже, после остальных. Если что, то галочку можно снять.

Comment: Я понял авторский вариант с одним тире и согласен с ним. В тонкостях (полное - неполное предложение) мне трудно разобраться, поэтому и задаю вопросы... А галочку можно снять всегда.

Comment: Самое сложное и спорное — в конце моего ответа (добавлено позже).

Comment: Авторское удивление не на месте, пауза уместна перед *раскулачили*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Случай очень нестандартный, непростой.

Здесь нет неполных простых предложений (в них пропущено подлежащее и/либо сказуемое), потому что это одно простое предложение, где присутствует сказуемое:
*...сослали кого на юг, кого на север.*
Если были бы, то перед первым "кого" обязательно ставилась бы запятая либо тире вместо неё, а она не ставится по аналогии с:
*Сослали кого куда.*
Если придаточное (простое неполное предложение), то можно подставить "того":
*Сослали того, кого на юг.* || Не подходит.
А оно равносильно следующему:
*Сослали одних на юг, других на север.*

Двоеточие употребляется для перечисления, здесь оно не обязательно, но два элемента, как здесь, для него маловато (не сильно удачно), желательно три и больше.

Если строго, то тире не должны стоять:
*...сослали: кого на юг, кого на север*.

Но в плане интонации из-за отдалённости глагола второе тире звучит по аналогии со следующим:
*Кого сослали на юг, кого — на север.* || Просто люди привыкли к такому.
То есть как бы интонационное тире (раз для него нет грамматических причин).

Двоеточие применяется при перечислении однородных членов предложения:
*Их сослали: на юг, на север, на восток.

Мы сослали: тех, других, третьих.*
Комбинация этого (разных членов предложения), как и в примере из вопроса, является нестандартной, в некоторой мере разговорной, в правилах не указана (не факт, что так можно).
Похожий пример:
*Он купил: крупы в магазине, овощи на рынке, хлеб в ларьке.*

Answer (score 2):

Оба тире возможны: оно ставится в неполном предложении на месте пропущенного члена предложения - сказуемого в данном случае.

Но в  неполном предложении разговорного стиля такие тире часто опускаются. Если же автор высказывания хочет подчеркнуть паузу, он выбирает тире на месте пропуска слова.

**В вашем примере "кого на юг" звучит без паузы, а в выражении "кого - на север" тире подчёркивает паузу.**

[Тире в неполном предложении](http://www.fio.ru/pravila/punktuatsiya/tire-v-nepolnom-predlozhenii/)  Тире ставится в неполном предложении, являющемся частью сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предшествующей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза, например: Они стояли друг против друга. Олег – растерянный и смущенный, Нина – с выражением вызова на лице (Фадеев); Карманы были двойные – внутренний – из полотна, внешний – из серого коленкора (А. Югов).

При отсутствии паузы тире не ставится, например: Алеша смотрел на них, а они на него (Достоевский); Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку (Чехов); Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леонов).

Comment: Но в этом предложении нет пропущенного члена: до двоеточия ведь есть глагол "сослали", а после нет неполных простых предложений, то однородные члены. Можно оформить так: *сослали кого на юг, кого на север*.

Comment: @JimKorbett Они есть в БСП, а не в простом предложении с перечислением, как здесь: *сослали кого на юг, кого на север* (двоеточие можно опустить).

Comment: Да, скорее всего.

Comment: oleedd, позвольте возразить. До двоеточия неопределённо-личное предложение с двумя однородными сказуемыми. После двоеточия идёт вторая часть БСП с однородными неполными неопределённо-личными предложениями, ср.: кого(сослали) на юг, кого (сослали) на север. Двоеточие очень важный знак здесь. Это двоеточие между двумя частями  БСП, где вторая часть поясняет первую, распространяя её содержание.

Comment: Нет, в БСП без знака не обойтись, а здесь его можно опустить. Это простое предложение с двоеточием для перечисления. Как минимум, этот вариант возможен, и он явно правильнее. Ещё в БСП члены предложения синтаксически не связаны, между ними нет падежного согласования, а здесь есть. При раскрытии содержания глаголы не повторяются. В БСП было бы как-то так: *...сослали: кого-то отправили на юг, кого-то — на север.* Вы вставьте там "а именно" для проверки — звучит плохо. Вы же предлагаете три раза использовать один глагол: *...сослали: кого сослали на юг, кого сослали на север.* Это тупо.

Comment: А в моём примере с "отправили" "а именно" звучит нормально.

Comment: Вот не думал, что моё предложение вызовет столько споров. Надеюсь, что польза от этого будет не только мне. Мне больше нравиться авторский вариант со вторым тире (это ответ в интервью, то есть можно отнести к разговорному стилю).

Comment: @Рад Это реально сложный случай, поэтому и спорный.